# How can I create a barseries plot using both grouped and stacked styles in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, bar-chart

The MATLAB [bar documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar.html) states the following:

> bar(...,'style') specifies the style of the bars. 'style' is 'grouped' **or** 'stacked'. Default mode of display is 'grouped'.

However, I would like to achieve **both** at the same time. Let me elaborate by giving an example:

```
Y = [1.0 0.5 0.7
     2.0 1.5 2.0
     5.0 4.0 5.0
     4.0 4.0 4.5
     3.0 2.0 2.0];

bar(Y,'group');
```

This code produces the following *grouped* barseries plot, with 5 different sets of 3 bars grouped together:

[image]

```
bar([repmat(0.5,5,1) Y(:,1)-0.5],'stack');
```

And this code produces the following *stacked* barseries plot, using just the first column of the above defined matrix `Y`:

[image]

I would like to merge these two, to get a barseries plot which is grouped and stacked at the same time. So the desired result would be like the first picture and each of the three bars in a set would be stacked like the second picture.

Comment: Could you post an example of a dataset that you'd like to be displayed like that? I just have a hard time understanding why you would want to do that.

Comment: I am trying to show these two things on one graph:
1) cost for each month using three different methods (x axis are months and there are 3 * 12 different bars)

2) breakdown of cost for each of these, as the total cost is calculated as a sum of two elements (lets call them static and dynamic part)

By doing that I can show on one graph the distribution of static and dynamic part in the cost and overall cost reduction by using different methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way I know of to get [BAR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar.html) to plot a combination grouped/stacked bar chart for you. However, you can do it yourself by adding rows of zeroes to your `Y` data wherever you want groups of bars to be separated, then modifying the x-axis [tick marks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#XTick) and [tick labels](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#XTickLabel) accordingly. Here's an example:

```
>> Y = [1 2 3; ...  %# Sample data
        2 3 4; ...
        3 4 5; ...
        4 5 6; ...
        5 6 7; ...
        6 7 8; ...
        7 8 9; ...
        8 9 10; ...
        9 10 11];
>> newY = reshape([reshape(Y,3,[]); zeros(1,numel(Y)/3)],[],3)  %# Add zeroes
                                                                %#   for spacing
newY =

     1     2     3
     2     3     4
     3     4     5
     0     0     0    %# <--- Note zero rows
     4     5     6
     5     6     7
     6     7     8
     0     0     0
     7     8     9
     8     9    10
     9    10    11
     0     0     0

>> bar(newY,'stacked');  %# Create a stacked histogram
>> set(gca,'XLim',[0 12],'XTick',2:4:10,'XTickLabel',1:3);  %# Modify axes
```

And here's the resulting figure:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

group vs stacked is an either-or type of information. you need to be creative to do what you want to do:

```
bar(Y,'stacked','BarWidth',0.3);
hold;
X = Y.*abs(randn(5,3));
bar(X,'stacked','BarWidth',0.3, 'Xdata', 1.3:1:5.3);
Z = Y.*abs(randn(5,3));
bar(X,'stacked','BarWidth',0.3, 'Xdata', 0.7:1:4.7);
```

quick rundown: start off with stacked data, make sure the `barwidth` is small enough to fit data properly to the graph, hold your plot, then add the other bar plot with a data offset (`Xdata`).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found this function to be quite useful and easily customized. I believe it provides another elegant solution to the grouped-and-stacked-bar-plot problem.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32884-plot-groups-of-stacked-bars