# Histogram from two vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have two sets of parallel vectors:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 55]; 
x_count = [7721, 6475, 3890, 2138, 1152, 784, 674, 492, 424, 365, 309, 302, 232, 250, 220, 208, 190, 162, 144, 134, 97, 93, 89, 97, 92, 85, 77, 87, 64, 75, 72, 82, 61, 48, 46, 44, 35, 20, 28, 20, 21, 10, 6, 8, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1];

y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 55];    
y_count = [88, 40, 24, 12, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 100];
```

where x, y are the categories, and x_count, y_count are the frequency of each categories. x and y can be of unequal lengths, and need not contain the same categories.

I want to create a side-by-side bar/histogram plot, where the x-axis is the categories, placed side-by-side like this: [side by side multiply histogram in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471924/side-by-side-multiply-histogram-in-matlab). The frequency counts go along the y-axis.

I've tried googling around, but still stuck on this. If someone could help, that would be great. The solution in [side by side multiply histogram in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471924/side-by-side-multiply-histogram-in-matlab) works only if x and y have the same length, but mine's not.

Comment: Ah yes, the value 10 should appear only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
% create unique bins
bins = unique([x y]); 

% create vectors with zeros same size as bins
xBins = zeros(size(bins));
yBins = zeros(size(bins)); 

% fill in counts in the respective spots
xBins(ismember(x, bins)) = x_count;
yBins(ismember(y, bins)) = y_count;


bar(bins, [xBins' yBins']);
```