# Combine the 'grouped' and 'stacked' in a BAR plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I know how to draw a `grouped` BAR plot and a `stacked` BAR plot as follows:

```
Y = round(rand(5,4)*10);
figure;
subplot(2,2,1); bar(Y,'grouped'); title('Group') % similar for 'hist'/'histc'
subplot(2,2,2); bar(Y,'stacked'); title('Stack')
```

This will generate something like:

[image]

My question is that **how can I combine options `grouped` and `stacked` in a BAR plot** to be able to generate a figure like the following (stack 3,4 together)? Or is there any alternative way to achieve this? P.S. I manually drew the following figure.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012568/how-can-i-create-a-barseries-plot-using-both-grouped-and-stacked-styles-in-matla

Comment: @hesar It's not a duplicate. That question talks about plotting groups of stacked bars, i.e. plotting stacked bars in grouped layout. My question is to show both at the same time. Thanks anyway. I will try to figure out how their idea can be applied here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this, the idea is:

1. Plot groups of stacked bars (need [`plotBarStackGroups.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32884-plot-groups-of-stacked-bars)).
2. Setting extra zeros to simulate original groups.

Combining these together, the code will be something like:

```
Y = round(rand(5,3,2)*10);
Y(1:5,1:2,1) = 0; % setting extra zeros to simulate original groups.

groupLabels = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};     % set labels
plotBarStackGroups(Y, groupLabels); % plot groups of stacked bars
```

And the result will be like:

[image]

Comment: So basically you found a file that does this at mathworks file exchange? that's great but maybe give more credit to the original author. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32884-plot-groups-of-stacked-bars

Comment: @Wolfie good point maybe I missed that was a link or something -- I'm not sure what I was thinking when I made that comment but you are right I was off base (though in retrospect I should have complained about a link answer without code  if anyone takes down that file from fileexchange this answer will be useless).