# Stacked bar chart in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I'm trying to create a bar chart in MATLAB where bar positions are in one column, bar heights are in another, and the bars are stacked whenever two or more positions overlap.

To illustrate, here is the same chart created in R with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(name=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'),
                   pos=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9),
                   height=c(2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1))

ggplot(data, aes(x=pos, y=height, fill=name)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width=0.05)
```

[image: stacked bar chart created in R]

For comparison, in MATLAB, the same data looks like:

```
data = [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9; ... 
    2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1]';
```

But I can't figure out whether there's a combination of parameters to the `bar` function to create the same sort of stacked bar chart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine the 'grouped' and 'stacked' in a BAR plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304962/combine-the-grouped-and-stacked-in-a-bar-plot)

Comment: @Anthony: It's not grouping. It's stacking with each bar having a different color, so not a duplicate.

Comment: @gnovice, you are correct. Sorry I falsely judged it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish this (it's a bit trickier in MATLAB):

```
[binCenters, ~, binIndex] = unique(data(:,1));
nBins = numel(binCenters);
nBars = numel(binIndex);
barData = zeros(nBins, nBars);
barData(binIndex+nBins.*(0:(nBars-1)).') = data(:, 2);
bar(binCenters, barData, 'stacked');
legend('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
```

[image]

The key is to format the data passed to [`bar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) into a matrix such that each row contains values for one stack, and each column will be a different grouping with different colors. Basically, `barData` ends up being mostly zeroes with one non-zero value per column:

```
barData =

     2     0     0     0     0     0
     0     4     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     3     2     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1
```