# How do I stack an array variable and plot three of these stacked array variables on a barh?

Tags: matlab

```
% S
a1 = [2015/07/23 2015/11/25 2016/01/20];
b1 = [2011/06/22 2014/10/14 2015/03/01];
c1 = [2012/04/16 2013/06/23 2015/04/08];
d1 = [2013/09/15 2014/01/19 2016/09/13];
e1 = [2015/04/01 2016/04/04 2018/08/04];

% H
a2 = [2012/07/23 2015/06/25 2016/05/20];
b2 = [2009/06/22 2014/09/14 2015/11/01];
c2 = [2006/04/16 2013/12/23 2015/06/08];
d2 = [2008/09/15 2014/05/19 2016/02/13];
e2 = [2011/04/01 2016/05/04 2018/03/04];

% HS
a3 = [2009/07/23 2010/06/25 2018/02/20];
b3 = [2011/06/22 2014/07/14 2016/09/01];
c3 = [2013/04/16 2016/09/23 2019/05/08];
d3 = [2013/09/15 2018/05/19 2019/06/13];
e3 = [2014/04/01 2019/01/04 2019/12/04];

% T
t = [1 2 3 4 5];

dates = [a1 a2 a3; b1 b2 b3; c1 c2 c3; d1 d2 d3; e1 e2 e3];

% Plotted
figure
barh(t, dates, 'hist')

title('Script')
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Tail')
legend({'S','H','HS'})
legend('Location', 'southoutside')
legend('Orientation','horizontal')
```

If you plot this, you will notice that there are 9 bar graphs associated with each 't'. There should be only three as stated in the 'dates' variable per t. How do I stack 'a1,a2,a3, then b1,b2,b3 ...... and e1,e2,e3 each individually' to accomplish this feat?

My script result:

[image: REALITY]

What I want the output to look like

[image: Fantasy]

```
Note: 1. The y axis contains the 5 different elements 't'
      2. The x axis should contain the date elements 'dates'
      3. When you plot these values, there are 9 bars. There should be three per 
      't'.
      4. On the x axis, I would like to have the dates represented.
      5. I would like to eventually be able to create a user prompted system that 
      allows people to enter in dates for a corresponding array, and have that 
      date be stacked onto the chart.
```

The following bit of code does a bit of what I ask for but with the bars stacked vertically not horizontally, and also takes in different user inputs.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32884-plot-groups-of-stacked-bars

Comment: I am pretty sure that you want to plot `dates` and not `d`(otherwise you raise an error and most of your code won't get used)

Comment: The "stacking" in your code quite irritates me. Why do you introduce  `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`? In `dates`, you concatenate 3 arrays per row (each consisting out of 3 elements, which makes `dates` a 3x3=9-column matrix), but you only want to see 3 bars? Maybe you can clarify what you want and how your code should work a bit more

Comment: For t=1 you are expecting 3 bars. Which length should they have? I see a total of 9 numbers in your data.

Comment: The code you posted really doesn't make much sense in this form. More than half of the variables are useless!

Comment: Greetings gentleman. response to Q1: yes, d=dates, forgive me.

Comment: Q2: there are 5 different elements, 't', that have 3 different properties (can be seen in dates), that are being changed wrt time. the values you see in the arrays and matrix 'dates' are actually supposed to be dates. my intention was to plot how these values change by changing the colours of the plotted and stacked bars but these stacked bars are changing wrt time. hope that makes sense.

Comment: Q3: the length of t is consistent (the number of elements in the array i mean). it will always remain 5 elements. the length of dates is also consistent, in that only three elements for each 't' will be plotted. The actual lengths of the individual a's,b's,c's....e's, is what will be dynamically changing as THESE arrays will be the ones that will have date values always being ADDED to them

Comment: Q4: please have a look at the modified values

Comment: @max please have a look

Comment: @daniel akefbieabf

Comment: @realreza hasfh

Comment: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304962/combine-the-grouped-and-stacked-in-a-bar-plot)

Comment: @max please see me other most recent question PLZZ

Comment: @realreza ^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to a solution. Download that file from MATLAB file exchange, open it, replace `bar` with `barh`, you got your own horizontally stacked bar plot.

Your input does not fit the expected format, the function expects a 3d matrix. A minor change to your code:

```
dates = [cat(3,a1,a2,a3);cat(3,b1,b2,b3); cat(3,c1,c2,c3); cat(3,d1,d2,d3); cat(3,e1,e2,e3)];
plotBarHStackGroups(dates,t)
```

Comment: The issue with the file from the exchange was not that I was unable to get the bars to display horizontally, I did that. The issue was that the inputs the file wanted were the data and the label of the bars. This is not what I want. My script will always have 5 tails and 3 properties per tails. The dates will be the changing variable. I am certain I can figure out how to link an excel file filled with previous dates to the script but having the script arrange the dates in the manner that I would like - THAT is where I get the issue. I want Matlab to recognize that the three properties are

Comment: changing with time and because of this, the bars should be stacked onto each other.

Comment: You wrote "The following bit of code does a bit of what I ask for but with the bars stacked vertically not horizontally" and now you write "The issue with the file from the exchange was not that I was unable to get the bars to display horizontally, I did that.". I have real troubles understanding what you are asking for. I thought I was answering your question.

Comment: Right, it 'does a bit' in the sense that for a specific element with three properties, it is able to group the values corresponding to each property and stack those properties. That is what I am trying to do in my code without success. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: please have a look at the updated question. It contains a picture of what I want the data to look like. Also note that the dates are not static. This script is created with the intention of being used in the future numerous times therefore the dates should ideally be in a dynamic array

Comment: I'm heavily confused by your original comment. "Your input does not fit the expected format" the format for my script or the one from the exchange? the function expects a 3d matrix." Are you suggesting I should link my script to the one from the file exchange? How do I do that?

Comment: Regarding your last comment, my answer already contains the modifications you have to do, replace the `dates=...` lines with one that concatenates to a 3d matrix.